# Is BP2.1 still planned?

Tags: light-clients

In February 2014 (over three years ago), Vitalik wrote in [a blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/02/18/ethereum-scalability-and-decentralization-updates/) that:

> Note that there is one weakness in this protocol: you now need to know all transactions ahead of time before processing a block, and adding new transactions requires substantial effort to recalculate intermediate stack trace values, so the process of producing a block will be more inefficient. However, it is likely possible to patch the protocol to get around this, and if it is possible then BP2.1 will have such a fix.

Has such a fix been produced?